# browser-sync can't run a server

Tags: node.js, macos, browser-sync

I use this command to run by browsersync/node server:

```
browser-sync start --server --files "**/*.html, **/*.js, **/*.css" --port 8005
```

The result I get is (which I can't find anywhere online):

```
[BS] Local URL: http://localhost:false
[BS] External URL: http://10.26.104.175:false
[BS] Serving files from: ./
[BS] Watching files...
```

I have no idea where should I start at diagnosing this problem. Does anyone has any suggestions?

browser-sync 1.9.0
node version v0.10.35
OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Answer (score 0):

Broken dependency in browser-sync inner dependency portscanner-plus/ portscanner
will use version ~0.2.2 (currently 0.2.3 which is not compatible)

Unistalling 0.2.3 and reinstalling portscanner@0.2.2 specific version fixed the problem. From browser-sync/node_modules/portscanner-plus/ directory run the commands:

```
npm uninstall portscanner
npm install portscanner@0.2.2
```